# How to open new fragment on Recyclerview Item Click?

Tags: android-recyclerview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, onitemclicklistener

I am using recycler view in a fragment. Now I want to open a new fragment on recycler view item click. I have used the following code in my recycler view adapter. Please solve my problem.

```js
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                MiscellaneousFragment miscellaneousfragment = new MiscellaneousFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.linerr, MiscellaneousFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });
```

But I am getting this error in Logcat.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.doAddOp.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 MiscellaneousFragment miscellaneousfragment = new MiscellaneousFragment();
                 FragmentManager  fragmentManager =currentfragment.getFragmentManager()
                 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linerr, miscellaneousfragment)
                 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
                 fragmentTransaction.commit()
            }
        });
```